# iphone app - Create a home button for NavigationController?

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

This is what xcode does by default: WHen you are viewing the first view in a navigation controller, the "back" button does not appear in the header.  The back button only appears when you travel to another view instantiated by the first view.

I want a home button, or back button to appear while you are on the first view.  Clicking on it will perform a certain action....like say change the rootviewcontroller.  How can I get this button to appear and how do I override it's behaviour only when on the first view?  The behaviour of the backbutton should work as default when on any other view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your root view controller's `viewDidLoad` method, initialize a `UIBarButtonItem` and add it to the navigation controller's toolbar:

```
UIBarButtonItem *homeButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                              initWithTitle:@"Home"
                              target:[AppDelegate sharedDelegate]
                              action:@selector(changeRootViewController)];
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButton:homeButton animated:NO];
```

The `target` should be your application delegate class if you want to swap out root view controllers. Create a method in that class called `changeRootViewController` to perform the view controller swap.

You can change the `homeButton` to use an image instead of text using [`initWithImage:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007519-CH3-SW3).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
UIButton *button =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
NSString* backBtnImg = @"myImage";
UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:backBtnImg ofType:@"png"]];
[button setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setTitle:@"back" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(myAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, buttonImage.size.width, buttonImage.size.height)];

UIBarButtonItem *btnItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = btnItem;
```